# Choose a particular string from text file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi I have a file with below content

```
    TAGS    Name    ASGonline-sys-system1-asg
    TAGS    aws:autoscaling:groupName   ASGonline-sys-system1-asg20210107040213164400000001
```

I want to fetch a particular keyword **ASGonline-sys-system1-asg** from this. but whenever I am trying to run below commands it is giving wrong output:

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> Select-String -Path C:\temp\instancename.txt -pattern 'ASGonline-sys-system1-asg'
    
    > C:\temp\instancename.txt:26:TAGS    Name    ASGonline-sys-system1-asg
    > C:\temp\instancename.txt:31:TAGS    aws:autoscaling:groupName    ASGonline-sys-system1-asg20210107040213164400000001
```

I tried another command as well Get-Content but seems same output only I am getting:

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Content C:\temp\instancename.txt | Where-Object { $_.Contains("ASGonline-sys-system1-asg") }
    TAGS    Name    ASGonline-sys-system1-asg
    TAGS    aws:autoscaling:groupName   ASGonline-sys-system1-asg20210107040213164400000001
```

I know it's a silly question but any mean I will get the output only **ASGonline-sys-system1-asg**

Whatever the name in the file comes it needs to give me that output only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!?

```
param(
    $exampleFileName = "d:\tmp\file.txt",
    $pattern         = "ASGonline-sys-system1-asg"
)

$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

@"
TAGS    Name    ASGonline-sys-system1-asg
TAGS    aws:autoscaling:groupName   ASGonline-sys-system1-asg20210107040213164400000001
"@ | Out-File $exampleFileName

$fileContent = Get-Content $exampleFileName -Raw

([regex]::Matches($fileContent, $pattern))[0].Value
```

```
Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      1      0
ASGonline-sys-system1-asg
```

Forgive me my English, as I understand it, you want to get the substring "ASGonline-sys-system1-asg" from the file's content. this can be done by reading the contents of the file into a variable and applying regular expressions to it.